# OO Design / Implementation in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop, database-design

I have an OO Design/Database question. I'm coding in Microsoft MVC v4 using entity framework 5.
Assuming model below:

```
public class Car
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set; }
  public int Wheels {get; set;}
}
public class Truck : Car
{
  public int CargoCapacity {get; set;}
}
public class Bus : Car
{
  public int PassangerCapacity {get; set;}
}
```

At a later stage I might want to expand the model so this has to be considered. eg: add a race car which has a property of 'NumberOfTurbos'.

Following good OO design principles:

**Question 1:** 
Should these all be in separate classes or all in one with modifiers.
Looking at separation of principles form the OO side I would say split them. Also closed/Open principle dictates that they should be split, which will help when I add the race car later an not have to change anything about a bus, truck, etc.

**Question 2:**
Should they all be in the same DB table? Even though I don't think the number of classes should dictate the number of tables, I still would go for separate tables so that the DB is normalized and there aren't unused fields all over the place. By default code-first puts it all in one table but I have split it with class schema attributes.

**Question 3:**
If I am supposed to be programming to an interface and not a concrete class (OO principles again) how would this work since if I have something like ICar which is implemented by the concrete class car, casting things to ICar will not work. Something like List < ICar > will not give me all correct data. Also implementing a MVC View to an Interface ICAR will be tough.

Should I even be putting interfaces on attribute-only classes? Should I be using something like a repository or some other patter/idea here?

Apologies for the long question and I appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.
Mike

Comment: Instead of using "Car" you should use something more generic e.g. "WheeledVehicle" as neither a truck nor a bus is a car.

Comment: Not to mention it would be really weird to see `public class Motorcycle : Car`

Comment: Yes, it was a bad naming choice, just for illustrative purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question 1: Should these all be in separate classes or all in one with modifiers. Looking at separation of principles form the OO side I would say split them. Also closed/Open principle dictates that they should be split, which will help when I add the race car later an not have to change anything about a bus, truck, etc.

Separate classes realistically, one class per item type. This will also be future proof as any changes you make down the line to any class don't necessarily have to affect the others. Anything added that will be shared in the future can just live on the base class.

> Question 2: Should they all be in the same DB table? Even though I don't think the number of classes should dictate the number of tables, I still would go for separate tables so that the DB is normalized and there aren't unused fields all over the place. By default code-first puts it all in one table but I have split it with class schema attributes.

No definitely not. Yes it'd be easier to query, but the volume of data you're querying actually increases. Plus you're effectively denormalising your database design, not to mention having a load of nullable fields that if are required by one type but not others can involve some ugly logic to validate.

> Question 3: If I am supposed to be programming to an interface and not a concrete class (OO principles again) how would this work since if I have something like ICar which is implemented by the concrete class car, casting things to ICar will not work. Something like List < ICar > will not give me all correct data. Also implementing a MVC View to an Interface ICAR will be tough.

You aren't *supposed* to be programming to interfaces, you should choose an interface/base class entirely dependent upon the implementation. I'd say in your example, just use a base class (something like `VehicleBase` that you can put all the shared properties inside of.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,

So we are basically in agreement on #1 and #2. Some more clarification on #3 please.
How would a view with an edit or list scaffold work in this scenario.

The common Vehicle items would be display first and then it would be a mess of multiple 
  
    "if is of type Bus
    then show bus attributes", 
    "if is of type Truck
    then show truck attributes"
   
And it would get very big and messy if I add a few more vehicle types.
Is there a neat/proper way of handling this?

Thanks

Comment: @MikeBryant To be honest, I'm not a fan of scaffolding, I prefer to do it myself. From an edit perspective, I wouldn't try and handle everything in one action, as that'd be a **mess** (especially as things grow). To keep things separate and futureproof, I'd have an edit action per type.

Comment: So you are saying in my vehiclecontroller I would have an EditCar(), EditTruck(), EditBus() and a separate view for each ? Actually then also a ViewCar(), ViewTruck(), ViewBus() and each edit method would have 2 versions one for load and one for save. Isnt that getting messy?

Comment: @MikeBryant It's not ideal, but it's the **lesser of the two evils** really. Your other alternative is one view with basically a `switch` statement on the vehicle type, then a model which is a mish mash of all the fields in all the vehicles.

Comment: yeah, that's something I want to avoid if/switch on entities to try preserve open/close and SOC. I think your idea of adding an action and view for each vehicle type might work better. I might even try abstracting the actions into some sort of class. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeBryant That sounds like a good idea. No problems glad I could help :). If this was the answer you were looking for, please click the tick next to it to mark it as correct. Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1:**

Yes these should be seperated out into multiple classes.  You can extend this further by marking `Car` as abstract since it is a base class for the other types of cars. You would also have to mark the properties as abstract too, as shown below:

```
abstract class Car
{
    abstract public int Id;
}
```

Although a better name for this could be `Vehicle`.

**Answer 2:**

You can store these in one table, called `Vehicle` and have a `VehicleType` table.

***Table Vehicle:***

> Id              VehicleName             VehicleType
>
> 1                 Toyota                1
>
> 2                 Kawasaki              2

***Table VehicleType:***

> Id                  VehicleDescription
>
> 1                    Car
>
> 2                    Motorbike
>
> 3                    Truck

**Answer 3:**

If you used an interface and had a List you would be limited to what properties/fields the `ICar` interface exposes.  You could however cast this to the appropriate VehicleType.

Comment: LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOL what are the chances, I mean really?

Comment: Programming on the iPhone again? Pr0 ;)

Comment: @mattytommo - 20MB broadband now ;) - off to sleeps.  See you in the morning for some SO reputation competition XX ~~

Comment: Nice, night mate! If your broadband wire gets cut it **definitely** wasn't me ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes they should be in different classes. Entities in your model shoudnt have properties that doesn't "belong" to them logically. When dealing with a `Truck` it most likely wont make sense to set or read `PassangerCapacity`. That will only be confusing.
2. this is a choice made in the ORM layer (EF in your case). EF supports single tables with columns for properties for all subclasses, as well as multiple tables for subclasses. both options have their merits. a single table has less joins so it might be faster, but several tables reduce the number of columns the db has to store, read and write so its potentially more efficient when it comes to storage. this all also depends what the actual datasets look like. this will however be abstracted by the ORM layer (EF) so in your object model they should still be separate.
3. If your code needs to deal with trucks, you should let it deal with trucks, for places when it only cares about Cars, use ICar. your database layer can expose datasets with cars and trucks and racecars down the line.